# Is this position of Egyptian dean of Islamic Studies really correct?

Tags: war

This comes from [this question](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/56289/did-an-egyptian-dean-of-islamic-studies-say-we-have-the-right-to-enslave-israel) in Sceptics but that another question itself only asks if the concrete person in question has said these words. Does Quran really gives such a permission? I was, to say so, impressed.

> we have the right to enslave Israeli women whom we captured in the war and enjoy them sexually

I would see a slave more like somebody on whom the ownership document has been issued as for a car, or otherwise long term relation agreed by community. Slavery is a kind of social order many nations went through so the religion obviously needed somehow tolerate this. Please explain in the context of war, when there has been no any slavery or other relation between the fighter and woman before.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are Muslim men allowed to take "sex slaves?"](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/649/are-muslim-men-allowed-to-take-sex-slaves)

Comment: Unsure, it is about slavery. Is any civilian in the country under attack automatically a slave?

Comment: There is disagreement among the schools of thought on whether female captives of war are 'automatically' enslaved but one certainly can be enslaved manually. See [Does islam allow killing or enslaving civilians in war?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/80381/20218)